# CSS crossfading images with different clickable links for each image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to have a crossfading banner where if you click the different images they send you to a different URL for each image. So far I have the object positioned and crossfading correctly and I also have all 4 images wrapped in an  tag taking you to one URL, but when I try to wrap each image in individual  tags for different URLs the individually wrapped images stop appearing in the crossfade and the link doesn't work. I've tried a nnumber of things to try and fix this such as:

```
<div onclick="location.href='#';" style="cursor: pointer;">
</div>
```

style="display:block"

```
<a>
<div>
"image" ( <- I now know it is illegal syntax to put <div> inside <a>)
</div>
</a>
```

All of which end up with any combination of images not appearing/only one link working/crossfade failing altogether.

I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS programming but I do have a background programming other languages and I have a feeling what I'm trying to do is quite easy and I'm just missing something. Thanks in advance for your help, please see code below.

```
/*HTML*/
<div id="cf">
<a id="StoreLink" title="Real Supplies Store" href="https://realsupplies1.merchanttribestores.com/products">Online Store&lt; 
<img class="top" src="../../images/sites/4968/storeassets/cleaning-equipment-banner.png" alt="" /> 
<img class="top" src="../../images/sites/4968/storeassets/secure-units-banner.png" alt="" /> 
<img class="top" src="../../images/sites/4968/storeassets/groundcare-banner.png" alt="" /> 
<img class="top" src="../../images/sites/4968/storeassets/heating-and-cooling-banner.png" alt="" />
</a>
</div>


/*CSS*/
#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
  }

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:-150px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  }

@keyframes cfFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  21% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  96% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

#cf img:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 21s;
}
#cf img:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 14s;
}
#cf img:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}
#cf img:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

#cf img {
animation-name: cfFadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 28s;
animation-direction: normal;
}
```

Comment: It is not ellegal to use a div tag inside a link tag. Ohter than that, it would be great if you could share an image of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Or a working example. Also, could you explain why exactly you put the div inside the `a`-tag? As far as I know, it's bad practice to put a `div` in an `a`-tag.

Comment: @Rvervuurt in HTML5 you can put anything inside the`a` element except interactive content. Look at the last code example of [this section of the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies. What I am trying to achieve is a banner on the website home page that will cycle through the images and when you click on one image you go to one part of the site and when you click another image you go to a different part of the site and so on. www.realsupplies.co.uk/test here is a test page that I've thrown together before I hack apart the home page. The above code produces what you see on that page. I hope that clarifies things a bit. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: This really isn't going to work. Whichever div or image is top of the stack is the one linked regardless of the opacity. You need to change the stacking order each time....this is something Javascript was built for,

Comment: Ok thanks all, I've now decided to use a carousel instead which works great for what I'm doing. Thanks again for the help.